# CSS keyframe animation doesn't animate image

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have a CSS snippet that makes an image fill the screen when it's clicked on, but for some reason it doesn't work. It uses `target` and `@keyframes`.  I isolated the problem in this Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/j2AKp/

*Note: the 2 seconds delay is intentional.*

The weird part is, the image does get bigger but there is just no transition. I click it, the delay works, then the image gets bigger instantly instead of over the 4 second period.

Comment: Works for me in Google Chrome

Comment: I'm using Safari, which also uses `-webkit-`... Weird.

Comment: It does work in chrome! That's really strange...

Comment: As a side note, if your animation is limited to that you might also want to consider using CSS3 transitions instead of animations. (but also not working as expected in safari)

Comment: Yeah, I'll probably use that. I just wanted to try out a few animations today.

Comment: I found that if the destination height is not 100% but a fixed value the animation works.

Comment: It really does need to be 100%, I'll find another solution... :/

Comment: I thought so. There are workaround to implement this using only CSS, but you might want to consider using JS to overcome this limitation. Sorry